# Can all unambiguous grammars be parsed in linear time?

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, time-complexity, parsing, context-free

When tinkering with noncanonical LR parsing, I thought up a parsing method (with infinitely sized tables, which makes it somewhat *unpractical*) capable of parsing exactly the unambiguous grammars in $O(n^2)$ time, and I wondered if it is possible to do better:

> Can all unambiguous grammars be parsed in linear time?

I'm quite sure I read somewhere that this is the case, but it doesn't come up when searching the internet. The same question was asked [here](http://compilers.iecc.com/comparch/article/91-04-021), but no answer was given as far as I know.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unambiguous context-free parsing is in $O(n^2)$ using Earley's algorithm.  Whether there exists a parsing algorithm working in linear-time on all the unambiguous context-free grammars is an open problem.  One of the most advanced statements of this kind is due to Leo [1991], who showed that a variant of Earley parsing works in linear time for all LRR grammars.

[Leo 1991] Joop M. I. M. Leo.  A general context-free parsing algorithm running in linear time on every LR($k$) grammar without using lookahead, *Theoretical Computer Science* 82(1):165--176. [doi: 10.1016/0304-3975(91)90180-A](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(91)90180-A)